# Random stratified sample from each factor levels

Tags: r, sample, r-factor, multisampling

I have data set with two factors: `Environments` (4 levels), `Individuals` (500 in each environment) and response variable `YD`.  As part of my analysis I have to randomly sample 100 individuals from each Environment in the following way:

1. Same 100 individuals across all the four environments(100 individuals)
2. Different 100 individuals from each environment  (100*4=400  individuals)
3. Same 100 in in 2 environment and another 100 in the other 2 environments (2*100=200 individuals)

I already solved this problem using several lines of code, however I hope someone will help me generate an R function to do that, which will be very useful in other situations.

Here is example data set with similar structure:

```
  library(BLR)
  data (wheat)
  Data <- melt(Y)
  colnames(Data) <- c('Individuals','Environments','YD')
```

Comment: **'stratified sample'** is the term for 'random sample from each factor levels'. Can you reword the question and your answer to be more clear what type of stratification you're implementing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**updated answer**:

I just wrapped the answer in a function. Note, that is valid only for exactly 4 levels.

```
colnames(Data)<-c("Individuals","Environments","YD") #removed spaces from names

myfun <- function(DF, samplefrom, samplelevels, sampletype, samplesize)
{
 if(sampletype == "per1")
  {
   Env1 = sample(unique(DF[[samplefrom]]), samplesize)
   Env2 <- Env3 <- Env4 <- Env1
  }
 if(sampletype == "per4")
  {
   Env1 = sample(unique(DF[[samplefrom]]), samplesize)
   Env2 = sample(unique(DF[[samplefrom]])[!unique(DF[[samplefrom]]) %in% Env1], samplesize)
   Env3 = sample(unique(DF[[samplefrom]])[!unique(DF[[samplefrom]]) %in% c(Env1, Env2)], samplesize)
   Env4 = sample(unique(DF[[samplefrom]])[!unique(DF[[samplefrom]]) %in% c(Env1, Env2, Env3)], samplesize)
  }
 if(sampletype == "per2")
  {
   Env1 = sample(unique(DF[[samplefrom]]), samplesize)
   Env2 <- Env1
   Env3 = sample(unique(DF[[samplefrom]])[!unique(DF[[samplefrom]]) %in% Env1], samplesize)
   Env4 <- Env3
  } 

  ret = do.call(rbind, mapply(function(ind, env) {df <- Data[DF[[samplelevels]] == env,]; 
                                                 df[df[[samplefrom]] %in% ind,]},
       env = as.list(sample(unique(DF[[samplelevels]]))), ind = list(Env1, Env2, Env3, Env4), 
            SIMPLIFY = F))    #in `env = ` added `sample` to select the environments 
                               #in random order and assign them the individuals

  return(ret)
}
myfun(Data, "Individuals", "Environments", "per1", 2)
#     Individuals Environments         YD
#21         13954            1  0.6658681
#345       457982            1 -1.1022770
#620        13954            2 -0.4888968
#944       457982            2  0.6026167
#1219       13954            4 -0.7183965
#1543      457982            4  0.4881141
#1818       13954            5  0.2660623
#2142      457982            5 -2.0626073
myfun(Data, "Individuals", "Environments", "per2", 2)
#     Individuals Environments         YD
#25         15292            1 -1.1272386
#248       373045            1 -0.6659416
#624        15292            2 -0.2362053
#847       373045            2  0.5778210
#1260       62150            4  1.2077921
#1654     1541043            4  1.1406084
#1859       62150            5 -0.3358584
#2253     1541043            5  0.3897426
myfun(Data, "Individuals", "Environments", "per4", 2)
#     Individuals Environments         YD
#106        85786            1  1.4480500
#567      3830162            1 -1.8052577
#1029     1301802            2  0.2737786
#1043     1410845            2  1.0617118
#1630     1302304            4  0.6673241
#1678     1766332            4 -0.0451913
#1871       65315            5 -0.0597450
#2336     2621166            5  2.5590801
```

**update 2** some comments

`mapply` applies a function sequentially to multiple arguments. Here, the function takes two arguments: `ind` and `env`. The function 1) subsets the dataframe by `env` and 2) subsets the subsetted dataframe by `ind`. `env` is an environment and `ind` is the sample of individuals (`Env1`, ...) previously calculated in `myfun`. The multiple arguments of the function to be `mapplied` are `env`: [1, 2, 3, 4] and `ind`: [Env1, Env2, Env3, Env4]. `mapply` takes sequentially `env = 1` and `ind = Env1`, `env = 2` and `ind = Env2` etc, and gives the result (the necessary subsets) in a list. `do.call(rbind,)` joins the list in a dataframe output.

P.S. Note that because `sample` is used `env` can be [1, 2, 3, 4] or [2, 4, 3, 1] or whatever and so the sequential combination of the function's (to be `mapplied`) arguments is not only `env = 1` and `ind = Env1` but `env = 1 or 2 or 3 or 4` and `ind = Env1`, and so on.

**update 3 and 4** function with different No levels

`No_different_samples` is the number of different samples you wish to take; I made it to default to the number of `samplelevels` (i.e. a different sample for every level). I made the function to give an error if the `No_different_samples` can't fit inthe No levels (i.e. if you want 3 different samples from a population with 4 levels (as your `Data`), it throws an error; you have to select either 1 or 2 or 4.

```
myfun2 <- function(DF, samplefrom, samplelevels, 
               No_different_samples = NULL, grouping = NULL, samplesize)
{
 samp <- sample(unique(DF[[samplefrom]]))
 levs <- unique(DF[[samplelevels]])

 if(is.null(No_different_samples)) No_different_samples <- length(levs)
 if(is.null(grouping)) grouping <- c(1, 1, 1, 1)    

 if(length(levs) %% No_different_samples) stop("an error message here")
 if(length(samp) < No_different_samples * samplesize) 
        stop("can't take a sample this large from the population")

 ls_diffr_samps <- vector("list", length = No_different_samples)
 for(i in 1:No_different_samples)
  { 
   ls_diffr_samps[[i]] <- samp[(i * samplesize - (samplesize - 1)) : (i * samplesize)]
  }

 list_samples <- rep(ls_diffr_samps, times = grouping)  

 ret = do.call(rbind, mapply(function(ind, env) {df <- DF[DF[[samplelevels]] == env,]; 
                                                 df[df[[samplefrom]] %in% ind,]},
       env = as.list(sample(levs)), ind = list_samples, 
            SIMPLIFY = F))     

  return(ret)
}

myfun2(Data, "Individuals", "Environments", 1, 4, 2) #same sample for all
myfun2(Data, "Individuals", "Environments", 2, c(2, 2), 2) #same sample per 2
myfun2(Data, "Individuals", "Environments", 2, c(3, 1), 2) #same sample for 3    
myfun2(Data, "Individuals", "Environments", 4, c(1, 1, 1, 1), 2) #different sample for all
```

Comment: Dear Alexis: thank you so much for your nice answer it is actually working and does what i need. But, as i mentioned in the question the challenge, at lest for me, is to put this answer in a function format.

Comment: Dear Alexis: Fantastic --- thank you --- i will accept your answer after trying it late today.

Comment: ALexis: In per2, can we assign  ENV at random --- you see i am worried about being biased because each time we replicate this function we chose that Env1=Env2 etc --- please let me see what you think?

Comment: @AaronD: I updated. When you run -now- `myfun`, the environments are set in random order. I added a comment to what I changed. I think I'm not missing anything.

Comment: Alexis: can you please explain the last part of myfun "ret" ? thank you so much

Comment: @hema: You 're welcome :). See if "update 2" in the answer is helpful.

Comment: Alexis: thank you --- I think the last part of your function we should replace Data by Df right? ------ one more favor, is that possible to make your function automatically accept different Environment levels i.e 4, 3, 5, 6 --- i just want to learn how, using this function as example-- again thank you so much

Comment: @hema: Yeah, you're right about replacing the `Data` with `DF`! I added "update 3" with a function accepting not only 4 levels. I hope I've not made any serious mistakes.

Comment: Dear Alexis:  can you allow No_different_samples=3, ---- practically this function will be used in the following way (as Aaron D mentioned ) 1- select 2 lines common across all 4 loc, 2- select 2 lines common in two loc and another 2 lines from another 2 loc, 3- 2 lines common in 3 loc and 2 lines from the fourth loc, 4- select 2 lines from different from each loc. thanks a lot

Comment: @hema: I changed the function but I didn't have to change the error, because no matter if the samples are grouped either 2 and 2 or 3 and 1, they are still 2 different samples. I added the argument `grouping` that is a vector of how should the different samples be grouped. E.g. if you want two samples where 3 will have the one sample and 1 will have the second sample, then `No_different_samples=2` and `grouping=c(3,1)`. The `length` of `grouping` should equal the `No_different_samples`. For 4 different samples, `grouping` should be c(1,1,1,1) i.e. 1 level for a different sample.Hope this helps